# what is remove_action when counting views in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get views of each post in wordpress and I go with this tutorial:
 [track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/cache/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/)

after functions, there is a line

```
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

What this line exactly do?
What will happen if I remove it?
What is "prefetching adding extra views"?

Answer (score 0):

Your are using-

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
```

This is used to remove previous and next links to posts.

For more clarity Please read the following link:
**https://isabelcastillo.com/remove-links-wordpress-head**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: why should we remove previous and next links for counting page views?